# Fingerprint Matching - generated Pattern, dont know how to compare - code attached

Tags: java, pattern-matching, fingerprint

I have generated fingerprint pattern using following project: https://fingerprint-rec.googlecode.com But, I don't know how to match two image patterns. I want to compare patterns, not images.  Please go through above code and help me.

Comment: Can please share the relevant parts of the code right here in the question? The link just points to the project main page. Chances are that nobody feels like reading all of the project's code to answer your question.

Comment: Check if it helps http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use co-efficient of correlation,basically an fingerprint would be an image ,so you can use some image improvement algorithms and then apply co-efficient of correlation(which is the degree of similarity between two matrix and basically an image is an matrix of pixels)